# Make a file unreadable for owner on Windows

Tags: windows, permissions, chmod, acl

I am working with the automated test suite of a software project. I have an automated test case that should verify that the code works correctly when a specific file is found, but the program does not have proper permission to read the contents of that file. This test case is currently working on Linux and macOS, but I am trying to get it to work on Windows as well.

The file is created by the test process, modified to have the read permission removed, and then the code tries to read the file, and the test verifies that the code fails in the expected way. After the test has run, the permissions are restored (if necessary), and the file is removed.

On Linux and macOS the read permission is removed by `chmod 000 unreadable.txt`, which makes the file unreadable by everyone (except root). I am trying to find a similar solution on Windows, where I can make this test file unreadable by the current user using command line tools, so the tested program can fail.

From my understanding, a command like `icacls unreadable.txt /deny 'Everyone:(RC)'` should have done the trick. `icacls` confirm the deny rule:

```
         Everyone:(DENY)(Rc,S)
```

but I have nevertheless full access to read the file.

I've tried various incantations of calls to `icacls` and `cacls`, with different combinations of trying to explicitly denying for my specific user account, etc. All to no avail.

I'm starting to wondering, is is impossible in Windows to disallow the owner of a file from reading it?

Or, if it is possible, what is the command line I need to make the file unreadable by the owner?

Comment: You may wish to describe your reasoning. The Windows Owner is (in numerous cases) the Administrator and can undo your changes.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not clear

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Be very VERY careful in Windows.  If you orphan a file, not even the administrator account will be able to retrieve it and you will have a dead file in your partition that you can't manipulate.  I have made this mistake before when working with the win32 security APIS (ACLs).  I assume that icalcs can do the same thing.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: That sounds unlikely to happen; if the usual SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege doesn't help (and it's supposed to help even against mistakes with the "owner rights" ACE), then SeRestorePrivilege can just straight up ignore ACLs.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72528318/what-file-permissions-make-a-file-unreadable-by-owner-in-windows